# Can someone explain the type syntax used in this OCaml program?

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml, variant, gadt

The types below are taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50586942/633183)

```
(* contains an error, later fixed by the OP *)
type _ task =
| Success : 'a -> 'a task
| Fail : 'a -> 'a task
| Binding : (('a task -> unit) -> unit) -> 'a task
| AndThen : ('a -> 'b task) * 'a task -> 'b task
| OnError : ('a -> 'b task) * 'a task -> 'b task

type _ stack =
| NoStack : 'a stack
| AndThenStack : ('a -> 'b task) * 'b stack -> 'a stack
| OnErrorStack : ('a -> 'b task) * 'b stack -> 'a stack

type 'a process = 
{ root: 'a task 
; stack: 'a stack 
}
```

I'm relatively new to OCaml, but I've never seen `:` syntax used like that before. For example, I've seen polymorphic types defined like this, using the `of` syntax

```
type 'a expr =
    | Base  of 'a
    | Const of bool
    | And   of 'a expr list
    | Or    of 'a expr list
    | Not   of 'a expr
```

In the original question, It's not obvious to me how the variants are even constructed, since it looks like each one does not accept an argument. Take this simplified example

```
type 'a stack =
  | Foo : int stack
  | Bar : string stack
;;
type 'a stack = Foo : int stack | Bar : string stack
```

Try making an `int stack` using `Foo`

```
Foo 5;;
Error: The constructor Foo expects 0 argument(s),
       but is applied here to 1 argument(s)
```

However, without an argument

```
Foo;;
- : int stack = Foo
```

Ok, but where's the `int`? How to store data in this type?

In the OP's program below, he/she is matching on the types "normally", eg `Success value -> ...` or `Fail value -> ...`. Again, how is this value constructed if the variant constructor doesn't accept an argument?

```
let rec loop : 'a. 'a process -> unit = fun proc ->
match proc.root with
| Success value -> 
    let rec step = function
    | NoStack -> ()
    | AndThenStack (callback, rest) -> loop {proc with root = callback value; stack = rest }
    | OnErrorStack (_callback, rest) -> step rest  <-- ERROR HERE
    in
    step proc.stack
| Fail value -> 
    let rec step = function
    | NoStack -> ()
    | AndThenStack (_callback, rest) -> step rest
    | OnErrorStack (callback, rest) -> loop {proc with root = callback value; stack = rest }
    in
    step proc.stack
| Binding callback -> callback (fun task -> loop {proc with root = task} )
| AndThen (callback, task) -> loop {root = task; stack = AndThenStack (callback, proc.stack)}
| OnError (callback, task) -> loop {root = task; stack = OnErrorStack (callback, proc.stack)}
```

Can someone help me filling in my knowledge gap?

Comment: The constructors that you've defined don't accept values, but the ones in the original program do. For a constructor to accept arguments, it should have a function type (such as `Foo : int -> int stack` or even `Foo : int * int stack -> int stack`).

Comment: Interesting. Can you explain the syntax in more general terms? What is the feature called? Can you infer why the OP would be using this instead of the `of` form?

Comment: In general these things are called GADTs (generalized algebraic data types). I am not aware of *the* good canonical tutorial introduction, but http://mads-hartmann.com/ocaml/2015/01/05/gadt-ocaml.html and https://blog.janestreet.com/why-gadts-matter-for-performance/ are both interesting reads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those types are Generalized Algebraic Data Types. Also known as [GADTs](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec251) . GADTs make it possible to refine the relationship between constructors and types.

In your example, GADTs are used as a way to introduce existentially quantified type: removing irrelevant constructors, one could write

```
type 'a task =
| Done of 'a
| AndThen : ('a -> 'b task) * 'a task -> 'b task
```

Here, `AndThen` is a constructor that takes two arguments: a callback of type 
`'a -> 'b task` and a `'a task` and returns a task of type `'b task`. A striking feature of this definition is that the type variable `'a` only appears inside the arguments of the constructor. A natural question is then if I have a value `AndThen(f,t): 'a task`, what is the type of `f`?

And the answer is that the type of `f` is partially unknown, I only know that there is a type `ty` such that both `f: ty -> 'a task` and `t: ty`. But at this point all information beyond the mere existence of `ty` has been lost. For this reason, the type `ty` is called an existentially quantified type.

But here, this small information is still enough to manipulate meaningfully such value. I can define a function step

```
let rec step: type a. a task -> a task = function
| Done _ as x -> x
| AndThen(f,Done x) -> f x
| AndThen(f, t) -> AndThen(f, step t)
```

which try to apply the function `f` in the constructor `AndThen` if possible,
using the information than the constructor `AndThen` always stores pair of callback and task that are compatible.

For instance

```
let x: int task = Done 0
let f: int -> float task =  fun x -> Done (float_of_int (x + 1))
let y: float task = AndThen(f,x)
;; step y = Done 1.
```

Answer (score 4):

I think comments and @octachron's answer provide enough details, but I would like to show my two favorite examples of GADTs power.

First of all you can write function which will return (kind of) different types!

```
type _ expression = Int : int -> int expression
                  | Bool : bool -> bool expression

let evaluate : type t. t expression -> t = function
  | Int i -> i
  | Bool b -> b
```

`type t. t expression -> t` means that function take some expression of some type and return a value of that type.

```
# evaluate (Int 42);;
- : int = 42
# evaluate (Bool true);;
- : bool = true
```

Clearly you can't achieve this with simple algebraic types.

The second point is that with GADTs compiler has enough information about the value you pass to the function, so you can "throw away" some senseless branch in pattern matching:

```
let negation : bool expression -> bool = function
  | Bool b -> not b
```

Because of `bool expression -> bool` OCaml know that `negation` works only for `bool` so there is no warnings about the absence of `Int i` branch. And if you try to call it with `Int i` you will see a type error:

```
# negation (Int 42);;
Characters 9-17:
  negation (Int 42);;
       ^^^^^^^^
```

> Error: This expression has type int expression
>          but an expression was expected of type bool expression
>          Type int is not compatible with type bool

With simple algebraic types this example will look like this:

```
let negation = function
  | Bool b -> not b
  | Int i -> failwith "not a bool"
```

You not only have one useless branch, but also if you accidentally pass `Int 42` it will fail only at runtime.

Comment: These examples are great! GADT is a topic that can easily throw off anybody looking into them for the first time, but these can be turned into a great introduction!