# What does the colon in this type definition mean?

Tags: ocaml, higher-kinded-types

I was reading about higher-kinded-types when I found the term `equality witness`, I looked up an example and found this type definition:

```ml
type ('a, 'b) eq = | Eq : ('a, 'a) eq
```

What exactly is going on here? I thought that that type would be the same as:

```ml
type ('a, 'b) eq = | Eq of ('a, 'a) eq
```

But they produce different looking outputs on the top level. What is going on with that colon, and what is that type?

*Edit*: I have another hypothesis that it means `Eq` is of type `('a, 'a) eq` but somehow not a type constructor. So the symbol `Eq` can be interpreted as `('a, 'a) eq`.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/what-does-it-mean-to-have-colons-and-arrows-in-user-defined-type-definitions/10166

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can someone explain the type syntax used in this OCaml program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591796/can-someone-explain-the-type-syntax-used-in-this-ocaml-program)

Comment: @glennsl Yeah this is roughly a duplicate. That post should have a better title, I searched long and hard on SO and I couldn't find it.

Comment: No worries. The point of linking duplicates is mostly that, ideally, you'd have differently phrased questions all pointing to the same canonical answer. Having several different posts asking the same question in different ways is a good thing. Having separate answers for each of them, not so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the syntax for declaring a **GADT** (for *generalized algebraic data types*), they are globally referenced here: https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/gadts-tutorial.html.
Sometimes you may want to make parameters depend on constructor sum types, GADTs allow this, for example:

```ml
type 'a t = 
  | String : string t
  | Int : int t
```

`String` will have the type `string t` and `Int` will have the type `int t`.There is a wide variety of uses for GADTs. In the example you give, the only possible construction of `Eq` implies that the type `'a` is the same as `'b`. So for example we can obviously define that value: `let _ : (int, int) eq = Eq` but not `let _ : (int, string) eq = Eq`. Seen like this, it doesn't seem very useful, but it is also possible to provide type equalities for syntactically different types:

```ml
type my_alias_on_int = int
let _ : (alias_on_int, int) eq = Eq
```

will typecheck. In other words, instantiating an expression `Eq` for which we have set the two type parameters implies that there is a witness that `'a` is of the same type as `'b`. So if, for example, I define an abstract type, but provide an equality witness (in a scope where my type equality is known), I can override the abstraction to have a proof that my abstract type is, under-the-hood, an integer:

```ml
module M : sig
  type t
  val eq : (t, int) eq
end = struct
  type t = int
  let eq = Eq
end
```

[this course](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1415/L28/gadts.pdf)
gives a very good overview of what can be done with GADTs, as does this [presentation](https://www.irif.fr/%7Egradanne/papers/gadts.pdf).